# Replacing All Chars (In StringBuilder) at their Index from of their occurrence another string

Tags: java, string, eclipse, char, stringbuilder

Okay, so I'm making myself a hangman game, not so new to Java, but I'm still learning. I've had an issue that has been bugging me.

I need to replace all Chars (If the user has guessed one of the letters correctly) within a String builder (that has the same number of characters as the generated word) at their index. A little complicated I know, but here's some of the code.

```
StringBuilder wordTemplate = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length(); i++) {
    wordTemplate.append('?');
}
```

This code creates a String with the same amount of characters as the generated word, and so if the word was "Hello" it would generate "?????" and as you guess each letter it would replace the corrosponding index of the letter (e.g if I guessed O, it would then print "????o" ect..)

However, if a letter reoccurs more than once, the guess only effects 1 letter, and that letter only, effectively breaking the game as the other occurrences are never changed thus resulting in the word never being completed. I have searched for quite a while and cannot find a solution to help me replace **all occurrences of the guessed char from their multiple index of the word.**

If it would help here's the code I currently use to replace letters from their index,

```
if (theWord.contains(guess)) {  
    wordTemplate.deleteCharAt(theWord.indexOf(guess));
    wordTemplate.replace(theWord.indexOf(guess), theWord.indexOf(guess), guess);
    System.out.println(wordTemplate);
}
```

As previously stated this only works for 1 of each char, and doesn't work for multiple occurrences. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String guess = "l";
    int start = 0;
    do {
        int index = theWord.indexOf(guess, start);
        if(index >= 0) {
            wordTemplate.replace(index, index + 1, guess);
            start = index + 1;
        } else
            break;
    } while (true);

    System.out.println(wordTemplate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the following code:

```
wordTemplate.deleteCharAt(theWord.indexOf(guess));
wordTemplate.replace(theWord.indexOf(guess), theWord.indexOf(guess), guess);
```

to

```
wordTemplate = new StringBuilder(wordTemplate.toString().replace("?", guess));
```